# python add value in dictionary in lambda expression

Tags: python

Is it possible to add values in dictionary in lambda expression?

That is to implement a lambda which has the similar function as below methods.

```
def add_value(dict_x):
    dict_x['a+b'] = dict_x['a'] + dict_x['b']
    return dict_x
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Technically, you may use side effect to update it, and exploit that `None` returned from `.update` is falsy to return dict via based on boolean operations:

```
add_value = lambda d: d.update({'a+b': d['a'] + d['b']}) or d
```

I just don't see any reason for doing it in real code though, both with lambda or with function written by you in question.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

_I just don't see any reason for doing it in real code though,_
I came here looking for a way to construct a dictionary using reduce (over a list of list of keys). How else would you that? Is there a better way?

Comment: That can be useful when trying to map a list of dictionaries and add a key-value pair to each. lambda d: {*d, 'a+b': d['a'] + d['b']} won't work for some reason (probably typing error)

Answer (score 0):

You could build a custom dict, inheriting from `dict`, overriding its `__setitem__` function. [See the Python documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html?emulating-container-types#emulating-container-types)

```
class MyCustomDict(dict):
    def __setitem__(self, key, item): 
        # your method here
```